# PHP unlink large number of files

Tags: php, centos, unlink

I have around 600k images in one directory, and i need to delete almost half of them with PHP. In one array i have stored names of files that need to be deleted and when I try to loop through array and call `unlink($filename)` **server crashes** after ~1k iterations and I must reboot it (CentOS 7). PHP memory usage is 81MB, and thats because of large array, which i have used because it is faster for some comparation against files in directory, not important.

```
foreach($filenames as $filename){

  // Deletes file
  unlink($filename);
}
```

I tought, maybe i should try `exec()`, but it's very slow, and after some time it freezes too. I have also saw a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548643/are-rename-and-unlink-asynchronous-functions) here about is it `unlink()` asynchronous, but I think it isn't.

I don't need `rmdir()` and deletion of directories, because all 600k files are in one directory, and relation between files and entities in application are stored in DB.

Is there any other alternative to delete files from PHP, or some advice how to make this thing work?

Comment: Are you running this from a browser? Or from the command line? If you're running something that takes a long time to execute like this, then its better not to run it from a browser

Comment: From the CLI of course

Comment: Why must this be done from PHP?

Comment: remove, for example 100 files at a time in this command, put this command to cron.

Comment: It doesn't need to be run from PHP, but i preffer, and if there is a way to do it in PHP, then why not, also i have a easy communication with DB, ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution. Firt write list of all files into `to_delete.txt` file (one filename per line) using `file_put_contents()`. Then run `xargs -a to_delete.txt -d'\n' rm` to delete files (xarg adds as much arguments as it can to rm, it doesn't run rm command for each file).