# Why does `rename` fail to delete the source file, when `unlink` works

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

I have a PHP script moving a file using function `rename`, which partly fails. Calling `rename` gives a "Permission denied" warning. The file seems to have been copied to the target directory (I see it there all right), but it is still present in the source directory after `rename`.

`file_exists` confirms that the old file is still present.
`unlink` can then successfully delete the file – it returns `true` and `file_exists` confirms that the file is gone now.

The file comes from being uploaded in an HTTP request into `/tmp` directory (and I'm using `is_uploaded_file` to satisfy security considerations – this is not the issue here). The file does have `rw` permissions for the webservice user (`www-data`). `move_uploaded_file` works without errors, too.

The destination directory is in a mounted CIFS directory.

Linux Ubuntu, PHP version 7.2.24.

Comment: The file could have been `fopen`ed and not `fclose`d

Comment: I expect it's chown/chmod issues.  What are the file ownerships and permissions of both the source and destination files, and their respective parent directories?  (ls -la, if you're on *nix).

Comment: @Cid, no nothing is being done with the file by the script other than moving, and nothing between trying to rename it and delete it.

Comment: @JānisElmeris can you show us the piece of code you are using to move the file ? (the `rename()` call should be enough)

Comment: Could be a [cache issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548685/8398549)

Comment: @wally source directory is `drwxrwxrwt` (`/tmp`), file is `-rw-------` with the webserver as the owner, the destination directory is in a mounted CIFS directory – not sure how related would be its permissions. But the thing is that I do see the "renamed" file in there, so there are permissions enough for the webserver to create a file in there.

Comment: @Cid, I added `clearstatcache();` after `rename` and after `unlink`, and `file_exists` still reported the same results – the file was still there after `rename`, and it was not after `unlink`. If that's what you meant by caching.

Comment: CIFS mounted directory would further suggest a permissions issue.  You can simulate what PHP is trying to do with `sudo`: `sudo -u www-data chmod 640 /target/file/path.txt`.  How was the CIFS path mounted?  Linux will still try to honour the (botched) CIFS permissions onto the local filesystem tree.

Comment: Oh and show us the output of `mount` listing the CIFS mount options.

Comment: @wally Yes, the simulation chmods all right but changing the ownership with `chown` is denied.

Comment: @wally Mount options would be `rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=devv,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=10.10.10.101,soft,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1`

Comment: `forceuid` might help. Unfortunately I’ve not got easy access to a box to test it right now. As per my comment on my answer - it looks like you’ve worked around the problem elegantly anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(**Updated:** OP says the target directory is a CIFS mount.  Permissions on CIFS mounts can be tricker to comprehend - see https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs section "*File And Directory Ownership And Permissions*")

`rename` isn't a single atomic action (in PHP).  It actually calls (in this order for normal files):

- `copy` (create a new copy of the file)
- `chown` (set the ownership of the new copy)
- `chmod` (set the permissions of the new copy)
- `unlink` (delete the original)

(Source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d1764ca33018f1f2e4a05926c879c67ad4aa8da5/main/streams/plain_wrapper.c#L1183).)

If any of these steps fails, it aborts with an error code, and does not rollback (which would align with the symptoms you're seeing).

*Side note: this is actually documented in the source code as possible behaviour:*

> ```
>  /*
>   * Try to set user and permission info on the target.
>   * If we're not root, then some of these may fail.
>   * We try chown first, to set proper group info, relying
>   * on the system environment to have proper umask to not allow                
>   * access to the file in the meantime.
>   */
> ```

I expect the permissions on the parent directory in the *target* (where you're copying *to*) are preventing the `chmod` or `chown` from working.

(**NB:** this will not work for a CIFS mount ... see link at the top of answer.) As a super ugly hack, you could try setting the permissions of the target directory to `777` (`chmod 777 /my/target/directory/`), which is bad practice, but would prove the theory.

Comment: Thank you for all the info and the pointer to the `rename` source! I decided to use `copy` + `unlink` instead of `rename` and it works (for my case anyway). `chmod` seems to work on CIF mounted files (we also checked the permissions on the origin server/filesystem, and they matched what we see in the locally mounted filesystem; not sure if that is odd or not), but `chown` fails. Chmodding the target dir to 777 (in the original filesystem) did not help.

Comment: So, does this mean PHP's `rename` may be used only by superusers? Isn't it too limited considering PHP scripts are mostly run by not-superusers, and renaming files seems a rather normal action.

Comment: I’m glad you’ve found a resolution! It means you may have issues if PHP isn’t running as super user.  Which, is to be expected for almost anything filesystem related. Your only alternative is to find a way of allowing `www-data` chown permissions on the CIFS mount... reading the mount.cifs docs, this should work by default - but evidently isn’t.  The `forceuid` mount option might help - but otherwise I think you’ve done the best thing by avoiding `rename` for this scenario.