# CMake fails to compile simple test, error 5 Access denied

Tags: cmake, mingw

I'm fairly new to CMake, and I'm getting the following output when I try to compile. I've been at this all day to no avail - does anyone out there have experience with this? Permissions on the relevant directories and files seem fine. Any help much appreciated! Thanks

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.2
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.2
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/buildtemp/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe
  "cmTryCompileExec2665670929/fast"

  C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2665670929.dir\build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2665670929.dir/build

  process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe,
  C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2665670929.dir\build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2665670929.dir/build, ...) failed.

  make (e=5): Access is denied.


  mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec2665670929/fast] Error 5





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Does your user have permissions to write into `C:\`?

Comment: Yes I think permissions were fine. A little further Googling suggested it might be firewall related, so I disabled Comodo Defense and hey presto the CMake configuration got paste the above error. Hope this helps someone else, thanks for the the reply.

Comment: I'd recommend to answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: i get a similar error with python3

process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\bin\python3, python3 C:/git/tool.py -m ./config/manifest.txt -i drv.bin -o drv.bin, ...) failed.
make (e=5): Access is denied.

Comment: This question was asked way to before, I had a similar issue today and turned out the problem was there was a special character (apostrophe') in the path of the project I was trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

the probem is probably caused by make deleting and creating helper .bat files. 
On windows, when deleted file is still referenced by other application (antivirus,windows indexing,etc), it is impossible to create file with same name. ([C++/Win32: How to wait for a pending delete to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764072/c-win32-how-to-wait-for-a-pending-delete-to-complete))
Make does use same name for newly created .bat file as the one just deleted and gets 'DELETE PENDING' error.

```
Date & Time:    29.3.2013 11:11:14
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  IRP_MJ_CREATE
Result: DELETE PENDING
Path:   D:\<truncated>\Debug\make6436-1.bat
TID:    6120
Duration:   0.0000149
Desired Access: Generic Read/Write
Disposition:    Create
Options:    Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File
Attributes: NT
ShareMode:  None
AllocationSize: 0
```

So disabling antivirus helps, but fixing make will be much better. Also you can try o make an exception in your antivirus software.